# Django : Passing api's json to template for use in a table

Tags: python, json, django, api

Currently I have my search function json_search in my views.py file like so:

```
def json_search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    api_key = locu_api
    url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=' + api_key
    locality = query.replace(' ', '%20')
    final_url = url + "&locality=" + locality + "&category=restaurant"
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
    data = json.load(json_obj)
    json_data = {}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

I am currently calling it through a form on my home page using url like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    "",
    url(r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="homepage.html"), name="home"),
    url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r"^account/", include("account.urls")),
    url(r"^loc_search/$", 'project_name.views.json_search', name="search"),
)
```

What I am looking to do is populate a table with the fields name: and phone: within the api's json I currently have the table set up :

```
<body>
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="{% url 'search' %}" data-cache="false" data-height="299">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="phone">Phone</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I know currently it is just returning the HttpResponse and dumping the json file so I get a blank html page like this:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 25, "cache-expiry": 3600}, "objects": [{"name": "Pizza Hut delivery", "locality": "Norwich", "website_url": null, "cuisines": [], "region": "Norfolk", "long": 1.27727303158181, "phone": "01603 488900", "postal_code": null, "categories": ["other", "restaurant"], "has_menu": false, "country": "United Kingdom", "lat": 52.6564553358682, "id": "00388fe53e4c9f5e897d", "street_address": null, "resource_uri": "/v1_0/venue/00388fe53e4c9f5e897d/"}, {"name": "Thai Lanna", "locality": "Norwich", "website_url": "http://www.thailannanorwich.co.uk", "cuisines": [], "region": "Norfolk", "long": 1.2788060400004, "phone": "01603 625087", "postal_code": "NR2 1AQ", "categories": ["other", "restaurant"], "has_menu": true, "country": "United Kingdom", "lat": 52.6273547550005, "id": "0452369b7789e15bb624", "street_address": "24 Bridewell Alley", "resource_uri": "/v1
```

I am just wondering how exactly I pass through the json data so that I can narrow down the search to my desired fields, I have tried using a rendor_to_response as well as a JsonResponse but I am stuck at just how to go about this now. I feel I have to alter my search function but I don't know just how.

Been stuck a while so any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: The json string you given is not a legal one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally managed to get it working i had to import within my views.py.:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

I was then able to alter my function to cater for parsing the object data through to my template like so:

```
def json_search(request):
query = request.GET.get('query')
api_key = locu_api
url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=' + api_key
locality = query.replace(' ', '%20')
final_url = url + "&locality=" + locality + "&category=restaurant"
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
decoded_data = json.load(json_obj)
return render(request, 'loc_search.html',
                   {'objects': decoded_data['objects']})
```

And then was able to call it after my form was submitted like this:

```
<ul>
{% for obj in objects %}
    <li>{{ obj.name }} - {{ obj.locality }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Giving the desired outcome :)

[image]

Hope anyone with a similar issue will find this helpful